# AngularJS: Is there a way to use $routeParams when not using Single Page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

> Or, I'm not doing Single Page in the strict sense ...

Hi,

First some

**Background**

I have the requirement that all previously loaded pages need to be persisted on screen, so that state is preserved without saving to storage. So I (think I) can't use the standard Single Page structure (using ngView). Instead I load MVC partial views and add them to the current page, while hiding previous entries.

```
apiService.View(viewInfo.Url).then(function (html) {
  var container = $('#' + self.targetContainerId);
  if (container) {
      container.html($compile(html)($scope));
  } else {
      loggerService.Info(self.Name, "Unable to find container '" + self.targetContainerId + "'.")
  }
});
```

- Where viewInfo contains the following (for the specific scenario I'm asking about):

  return {
    Breadcrumb: 'People',
    Url: 'Partial/PeopleOverview' + '/' + options.ScreenContextId + '/' + options.RoleTypeId
  };

apiService.View does the following:

```
return {
    View: function (uri) {
        return self.DoViewRequest('get', uri);
    }
}
```

Based on:

```
self.DoViewRequest = function (verb, uri) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    verb = verb.toLowerCase();

    //start with the uri
    var httpArgs = [coreUtilityService.GetLocalUrl() + uri];
    if (verb.match(/post|put/)) {
        httpArgs.push(data);
    }

    $http[verb].apply(null, httpArgs)
    .success(function (response) {
        defer.resolve(response);
    })
    .error(function (response, status) {
        defer.reject('HTTP Error: ' + status);
    });

    return defer.promise;
};
```

**What I need to solve**

*ScreenContextId* and *RoleTypeId* are vital information which I need to pass throughout the structure. It is received from the calling url, which is this:

*/Home/People/0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e/7c9e6679-7425-40de-944b-e07fc1f90ae7*

It would be very easy if I could use *$routeParams*, but as I'm not using Single Page in the strict sense, I don't think it's available. I've set up routing like this:

```
.config([
    '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when('/Home/People/', {
            templateUrl: '/Home/People/:screenContextId/:roleTypeId'
        });
    }
])
```

With this, I would then (theoretically) be able to use:

*$routeParams.screenContextId
$routeParams.roleTypeId*

**The question**

Is it possible to use *$routeParams* given the required context, or are there alternatives that I should use?

Or, is there a way to use Single Page and meet my requirements (without persisting state to storage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you can use $location.search(). It will give you object with similar / same structure as $routeParams.

Sorry, remembered that incorrectly, use $location.path().split('/'), you will get array of path params, then just access the correct one with index.

Comment: Ah yes, I was about to ask whether that works for REST urls :). However, path seems to be empty. $$absUrl contains the complete url though. That would work, but then the entire url is split, resulting in an array of strings containing seven entities, of which I only need two. Is there a more elegant alternative?

Comment: As far as i know no, but you can abstract that functionality in your custom service :)

Comment: I'll postpone selecting this as an answer to allow other people to present alternatives that are perhaps a little more elegant, but it does get the job done :).

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, would also like to learn about better way tp do that, until then enjoy :)

Comment: $location is only a partial solution because it doesn't work when calling an MVC partial view. Specifically, the controller script on the partial view has the page's url in $location, NOT the one of the partial view being called. This means I'm not getting the correct parameter info.

Comment: Putting the required information aside in $rootScope works, but I don't know if it's the preferred way?

Comment: Unfortunately not cuz scope is deprecated in angular 2, its better to create service for storing of shared data. Services are singletons so you can inject and acces them anywhere in app.